# Drop down or radio button for selecting shapefile layers in ArcGIS map / Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis, esri

In Esri ArcGIS Experience Builder, is it possible to create an app with a single map consisting of multiple shapefile layers, where the user can ONLY select to view ONE layer at a time?

I would like to have radio buttons or a drop-down menu that determines layer visibility rather than tick-boxes in the map layers widget.